# would like to print extra charachter after same match which is only 's' in this case

Tags: python

print 's' only from the following string after match like: things and night having same string and s is extra which need to print to the console

```
s1 = 'things'
s1 = sorted(s1)
s2 = 'night'
s2 = sorted(s2)

l1 = len(s1)
l2 = len(s2)

max_len = max(l1,l2)
# max_len = list(map(int, str(max_len)))

if s1[0:] != s2[0:]:
  for i in range(max_len):
    if s1[i] == s2[i]:
      print(s1[i])
```

Expected output: = `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) difference to get all the chars that are in either string but not in the other:

```
from collections import Counter

def diff(s1, s2):
    c1, c2 = Counter(s1), Counter(s2)
    return "".join(((c1-c2) + (c2-c1)).elements())
    
diff("things", "night")
# 's'
diff("abcd", "cdef")
# 'abef'
```

A simpler approach, using a generator:

```
def diff(s1, s2):
    for c in s1: 
        if c not in s2:
            yield c
    for c in s2: 
        if c not in s1:
            yield c

[*diff("things", "night")]
# ['s']
[*diff("abcd", "cdef")]
# ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

This will however neglect differing counts of the same character.

Comment: is there to solve the problem on my above way of code

Comment: I guess the sorting approach is not generally applicable. What if the two sorted strings do not have a common prefix (that also happens to exhaust one of them)? Or is there more logic to it? What about other inputs? What about  multiple occurrences of the same letter?

Comment: if the string in two inputs doesn't match each other value those value can we print it, that's what I am trying to print. by the way, your code is absolutely correct but I need it as simple as it can.